# in THTMLViewer some fonts are not justified

Tags: delphi, fonts, justify, text-justify

I have simple html code

```
<FONT SIZE = 5>
<p style="font-family:calibri" align="justify">long long long simple text...</p>
</FONT>
```

In ThtmlViewer some fonts are justified (ex. Arial), but other are not (ex. Calibri)
Why?
Is it a font issue or HTMLViewer?

Comment: The `font` element and the `align` attribute have both been deprecated for 20 years. Please don't use them.

Comment: So what do you propose instead, which will operate in HTMLViewer?

Comment: Everyone uses CSS now. Still, this might not be related to your actual question. One reason why you haven't received many replies is that you haven't told us what a `THTMLViewer` is. That's not a component that is installed by default in modern Delphi (unlike `TWebBrowser`). Since we don't know what component you are using, we cannot really help you.